# MS Access - trying to find duplicates across 4 tables based on Column1 and Column2

Tags: sql, ms-access

MS Access - trying to find duplicates across 4 tables based on the info in Column1 and Column2. I would also like the resulting query to show me Column3, Column4 and Column5 for easy review. I've tried following a Youtube vid on a union query and was successful.. But that's as far as I can go. I tried to follow along some of the answers but I cant make it work. Just note that I have 0 programming language knowledge. Tyvm in advance!

Column1 = Unique reference
Column 2 = Loss date

Duplicates happen when a row has same unique ref and same DOL. This can be within the table or across tables. Like one entry is in Table2019 and another one is in Table2022. Or two entries in Table2019 with four more spread in other tables.

```
SELECT [t2019].ID, [t2019].[ClaimNo], [t2019].DOL, [t2019].[Amount], [t2019].[Cause], [t2019].[Ref], [t2019].[Regn], [t2019].Remarks
FROM [t2019] 

UNION

SELECT [t2020].ID, [t2020].[ClaimNo], [t2020].DOL, [t2020].[Amount], [t2020].[Cause], [t2020].[Ref], [t2020].[Regn], [t2020].Remarks
FROM [t2020]

UNION

SELECT [t2021].ID, [t2021].[ClaimNo], [t2021].DOL, [t2021].[Amount], [t2021].[Cause], [t2021].[Ref], [t2021].[Regn], [t2021].Remarks
FROM [t2021]

UNION 

SELECT [t2022].ID, [t2022].[ClaimNo], [t2022].DOL, [t2022].[Amount], [t2022].[Cause], [t2022].[Ref], [t2022].[Regn], [t2022].Remarks
FROM [t2022];
```

Comment: When you say duplicates, do you mean a duplicate value in field 1 or 2 or when both 1 & 2 are the same?  Do you mean the col 1 & col 2 are duplicated in another row or 1 & 2 are the same in a row?  Can you explain a little more about dupes.  Is a dupe a dupe if it's in table 1 twice or table 1 & 2

Comment: What are column 1 and column 2?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I’ve updated the post to clarify what I meant by dupes. Sorry if I wasnt clear earlier. Basically if data in Col1 and Col2 are duplicated in another row, within the same table or in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Access has a wizard to help write the relatively difficult SQL for finding duplicate records.  So first gather up all the records that need to be searched for duplicates then use the wizard.

To gather the records open the query designer, go to the SQL Pane, SELECT union and adapt the following SQL:

[image]

Unfortunately, there is no graphical interface to help.
Get Typing and don't forget that semi-colon.  UNION is used to combine SELECT statements.  So were combining everything from all the tables.  the ALL is important because by itself UNION ignores rows where every column is an exact match to a previous row.  We are looking for duplicates so we add ALL to include those skipped rows.

When you have all the rows go to query wizard under the create tab and run the find duplicates wizard:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the resulting SQL for my example data:

```
SELECT Query1.[ID], Query1.[DOL], Query1.[ClaimNo], Query1.[Amount], Query1.[Cause], Query1.[Ref], Query1.[Regn], Query1.[Remarks]
FROM Query1
WHERE (((Query1.[ID]) In (SELECT [ID] FROM [Query1] As Tmp GROUP BY [ID],[DOL] HAVING Count(*)>1  And [DOL] = [Query1].[DOL])))
ORDER BY Query1.[ID], Query1.[DOL]
```

Note:
In Access ID is a primary key and AutoNumber by default.  It looks suspicious here.  If the default settings are intact and you are entering data in Access then every table starts with ID 1 and you have duplicate ID's in every table.  Instead, I would normally combine all these year tables using a year column.  This also avoids the union query.  I would only use year tables if I had millions of records and couldn't afford the space for a year column.